# /.../ What does this Ruby regex mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

What does this Ruby regex mean?

```
/.../
```

Comment: The dot `.` matches _any single character_, so that regex matches any 3 characters.

Comment: And it doesn't have to be exactly a 3 character string either, because it isn't `^$` anchored. It just has to be any string at least 3 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

This regex matches any three characters.